# GWT application crashes in latest Firefox versions 21 and above

Tags: firefox, gwt

We have a GWT application which crashes in Firefox versions 21 and above, including in the latest version 23.0.1. In earlier versions of Firefox and IE 9, it works fine. This is in deployed mode and not because of the GWT plugin. The situation it crashes is when there are huge number of RPC calls, may be around 300 to 400.

As the application in which it happens is fairly complex, I tried to simulate this issue with a simple prototype. I observed that my prototype crashes when the number of RPC calls reach 100000. But this scenario is very unlikely in my application where RPC calls are around 300-400 as observed using Firebug.

I am trying to find out what else I am missing in my prototype so that it also crashes with 300-400 RPC calls.

GWT version - 2.4
GXT version - 2.2.5

```
package com.ganesh.check.firefox.client;
public class FirefoxCrash implements EntryPoint {

private static final String SERVER_ERROR = "An error occurred while "
        + "attempting to contact the server. Please check your network "
        + "connection and try again.";


private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
        .create(GreetingService.class);

public native static void consoleLog(String text)/*-{
                                        $wnd.console.log(text);
                                        }-*/;

public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
    nameField.setText("GWT User");
    final Label errorLabel = new Label();
    final Label countLabel = new Label();

    // We can add style names to widgets
    sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");

    // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
    // Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element
    RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
    RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
    RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);
    RootPanel.get("count").add(countLabel);

    // Focus the cursor on the name field when the app loads
    nameField.setFocus(true);
    nameField.selectAll();

    // Create the popup dialog box
    final DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();
    dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
    dialogBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    final Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
    // We can set the id of a widget by accessing its Element
    closeButton.getElement().setId("closeButton");
    final Label textToServerLabel = new Label();
    final HTML serverResponseLabel = new HTML();
    VerticalPanel dialogVPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    dialogVPanel.addStyleName("dialogVPanel");
    dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<b>Sending name to the server:</b>"));
    dialogVPanel.add(textToServerLabel);
    dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<br><b>Server replies:</b>"));
    dialogVPanel.add(serverResponseLabel);
    dialogVPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    dialogVPanel.add(closeButton);
    dialogBox.setWidget(dialogVPanel);

    // Add a handler to close the DialogBox
    closeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            dialogBox.hide();
            sendButton.setEnabled(true);
            sendButton.setFocus(true);
        }
    });


    class MyHandler implements ClickHandler, KeyUpHandler {

        private int resultCount = 0;

        /**
         * Fired when the user clicks on the sendButton.
         */
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            sendNameToServer();
        }

        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                sendNameToServer();
            }
        }


        private void sendNameToServer() {
            // First, we validate the input.
            errorLabel.setText("");
            String textToServer = nameField.getText();

            // Then, we send the input to the server.
            textToServerLabel.setText(textToServer);
            serverResponseLabel.setText("");
            final int loopCount = Integer.parseInt(textToServer);
            resultCount=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
                greetingService.getResult(textToServer,
                        new AsyncCallback<ResultBean>() {
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                consoleLog(caught.getMessage());
                            }

                            public void onSuccess(ResultBean result) {
                                //countLabel.setText(++resultCount + "");
                                resultCount++;
                                if(resultCount==loopCount){
                                    countLabel.setText(resultCount + "");
                                }
                                consoleLog("Result returned for "+resultCount);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

    // Add a handler to send the name to the server
    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
    sendButton.addClickHandler(handler);
    nameField.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
}
}

public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
GreetingService {

public ResultBean getResult(String name) {
  ResultBean result = new ResultBean();
  Random random = new Random();
  int suffix = random.nextInt();

  result.setName("Name "+suffix);
  result.setAddress("Address "+suffix);
  result.setZipCode(suffix);
  result.setDoorNumber("Door "+suffix);
  return result;
}


public class ResultBean implements Serializable {
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public String getDoorNumber() {
    return doorNumber;
}

public void setDoorNumber(String doorNumber) {
    this.doorNumber = doorNumber;
}

private String name;
private String address;
private int zipCode;
private String doorNumber;

  }
```

Comment: If by "crash" you mean "is out of memory", maybe you could use a profiler ?

Comment: By crash, I mean Firefox closes.

Comment: It seems Firefox issues crash reports, which can be analyzed. Like here https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/967406 May I suggest you to try to produce one, and simultaneously post this matter to the Firefox forums in no one on stack can answer.